# Add pytest.mark dynamically to a testcase

Tags: python, automation, pytest

I have added a datafile to drive and pass arguments to my testcases. Depending on the arguments passed, I would like to also "mark" each testcase dynamically from the datafile.

I've been reading the documentation and checking the source code, I cant seem to figure it out.

Any way to do this?

Example:

**datafile.yaml**

```
testcase1:
    data1: value1
    mark:
         - sanity
         - scale
```

**datafile2.yaml** - Different value and different mark

```
testcase1:
    data1: value3
    mark:
         - sanity
         - smoke
```

**testcase.py** - No mark in the testcase file - they would be all added dynamically

```
def test_somename(datafile_data):
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the markers in collection time before the test starts. You can do it by getting the data from the file and passing it to the test function using `parametrize` annotation

```
def get_data():
    data1, marks = 'value', ['sanity', 'scale'] # the data from the file
    marks = [Mark(name, (), {}) for name in marks]
    yield pytest.param(data1, marks=marks)


@pytest.mark.parametrize('datafile_data', get_data())
def test_somename(datafile_data):
    ...
```